# How do I read in an existing jar's manifest, and append to its classpath using Ant

Tags: java, ant

I want to add a target to my Ant script that reads in a jar's manifest and appends a new jar at the end. I've looked at `loadproperties` task, and it seemed close, but unable to handle when the classpath is split up among multiple lines. So does anyone know if this is possible with the out-of-the-box Ant tasks?

Comment: It might have been handy to mention the obvious answer & why it does not suit the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/ManifestReader.aspx), I modified it to read in the existing classpath, append a new jar file at the end and then save it to a property. At that point, it's easy to write back out using the manifest task.

```
public void execute() throws BuildException {
    validateAttributes();

    checkFileExists();

    JarFile jarFile = null;     
    Manifest manifest = null;

    try {
        jarFile = new JarFile(directory + "/" + jar);
        manifest = jarFile.getManifest();
        Attributes attributes = manifest.getMainAttributes();
        String currClasspath = attributes.getValue("Class-Path");

        String newClasspath = currClasspath.concat(" ").concat(append);

        getProject().setProperty(propertyName, newClasspath);           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new BuildException();
    } finally {
        if (manifest != null) {
            manifest = null;
        }
        if (jarFile != null) {
            try {
                jarFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
            jarFile = null;
        }

    }
}
```

The getters/setters/utility methods omitted for space. Then the Ant code looks like this:

```
<target name="addToClasspath" depends="build">
    <property name="testPath" value="C:/"/>     

    <taskdef name="manifestAppender" classname="ClasspathAppender" />

    <manifestAppender dir="${testPath}" jar="wbclasspath.jar" append="test.jar" property="newClasspath" />

    <echo>Manifest class-path: ${newClasspath}</echo>

    <jar destfile="${testPath}/wbclasspath.jar">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${newClasspath}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>      
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [manifest task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html) in `update` mode would seem the obvious answer.

Comment: If I set the Class-Path in a manifest task in update mode, that'll overwrite what's already there. I want to append. This is obviously what needs to take place AFTER the existing class path has already been read in and modified.